# PHP - Hashing an image without antialiasing

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

I am hashing images using MD5 in order to be able to identify duplicate images being uploaded. On the whole this has been working quite well, however I have recently noticed duplicate images with different hashes.

I have two images which appear on the surface to be identical but then compared using an online tool they seems to be different

In colour the images are 0.4% different, and black & white they are 0.1% different, and when "Ignore antialiasing" is selected they are identical.

So what am wanting to know is, how can I generate an image hash without this "antialiasing"?

I couldn't really find anything on Google which was much help either :/

---

**Update**

I have installed ImageMagik on the server and now hashing images like this:

```
$imagick_type = new Imagick();
$file_to_grab = "60a4ogfrd565no2dfzctfy4gpwaqib1pcct0s9s6ezb2nef3es.jpg";
$file_handle_for_viewing_image_file = fopen($file_to_grab, 'a+');
$imagick_type->readImageFile($file_handle_for_viewing_image_file);
$imagick_type_signature = $imagick_type->getImageSignature();
print($imagick_type_signature);
```

The 2 images in question though are still returning different hashes.

Comment: First of all, you must create a hash of the _image_, not the _image file_. The image file may contain EXIF data, GPS data or text comments.

Comment: Does this solve the antialiasing problem?

Comment: Creating a hash of the _image data_ should not do any antialiasing. It is just a numerical algorithm crunching the image bytes.

Comment: Right, now I understand :)

Comment: I used a script a few years back to do this. It called a linux program like this: `jpegtran -copy none "$1" | md5sum` This will calculate the md5 sum of a copy of the image, without additional data.

Comment: Please see my update above

Comment: Sorry, can not help you wit this. How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25126397/4405465)?

Comment: Here is [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1377780/4405465) page with some useful tips